# How do I count rows so that consecutive occurence of data counts as 1?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

The scenario is I am trying to count the occurrences of data in my table, except I would like to count consecutive occurrences as 1. Here's an example.

Input:

```
|item    |statusid|
|--------|--------|
| pencil | A      |
| pencil | B      |
| pencil | C      |
| pencil | A      |-Counts
| pencil | A      |-as one
| pencil | B      |
| pencil | A      |
| eraser | D      |-Counts
| eraser | D      |-as one
| eraser | E      |
| eraser | F      |
| eraser | D      |
| eraser | E      |
| eraser | F      |
```

How would I do this in SQL Server using a stored procedure to output something like this:

Output:

```
|item    |statusid|occurence|
|--------|--------|---------|
| pencil | A      |  3      |
| pencil | B      |  2      |
| pencil | C      |  1      |
| eraser | D      |  2      |
| eraser | E      |  2      |
| eraser | F      |  2      |
```

Edit: The table assumes that there is a datetime column which can be used for ordering the rows.

Comment: The problem is that you need something to define the order. There is nothing in your sample here to define the order of rows.

Comment: Lets start with the basics. Is this sample set accurate to what you are dealing with if not can you make it more accurate. What have you tried so far. What has worked and what has not. These are all  helpful items when posting a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `lag()` window function:

```
select [item], [statusid], count(*) occurence 
from (
  select *, 
    lag([item]) over (order by (select null)) previtem,
    lag([statusid]) over (order by (select null)) prevstatusid
  from tablename
) t
where [item] <> previtem or [statusid] <> prevstatusid or (previtem is null and prevstatusid is null)
group by [item], [statusid]
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1de8f24b190dbce9a5ef1446fa30dcda).
Results:

```
> item   | statusid | occurence
> :----- | :------- | --------:
> pencil | A        |         3
> pencil | B        |         2
> pencil | C        |         1
> eraser | D        |         2
> eraser | E        |         2
> eraser | F        |         2
```

**Note**: check the link in one of @SeanLange 's comments.
This code will work for the sample data you posted and for a relatively small table but not in a really large table.
In any case you will need a column that determines the order of the rows.

Comment: This works with a small sample because the default order just happens to be the same order the rows were inserted. This will NOT work on a real table unless you have a column you can count on for ordering.

Comment: The requirement is about the rows as they were inserted. For this requirement this code DOES work.

Comment: No it does not. It works on this small data set by accident. The OP has nothing to use as an order by, so you used SELECT NULL. This only happens to work here because the table is incredibly small. But this is relying on data being returned in a certain order and you can't ensure that without a column to order by. It is the same problem explained in this article. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/conor_cunningham_msft/2008/08/27/no-seatbelt-expecting-order-without-order-by/

Comment: Follow the examples in that article and you will see there is a tipping point where the rows are no longer returned in insertion order. And it explains why. Your code would work perfectly IF the OP had a column you can use to define the order.

Comment: @SeanLange the link you posted is very interesting and useful. Another proof that taking for granted solutions for cases like this, would lead to unpredictable results. I will edit to mention the problem.

Comment: If the OP listens to the advice about having a column to use for ordering this solution works great. If they don't...well...they have been warned.

Comment: Hello. Apologies for not including the column for ordering the data. All your input helped me solve the problem. Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 0):

```
with cte as
 (
   select item, statusid,
      -- tag consecutive rows with the same status
      case when lag(statusid) 
                over (partition by item
                      order by whatever) = statusid -- same status
           then 0 -- remove or
           else 1 -- keep in next step
      end as flag
   from mytable
 )
select item, statusid, count(*)
from cte
where flag = 1 -- now remove those rows
group by item, statusid
```

Comment: This only sorta kinda works in theory. But you don't have an ORDER BY with your LAG function. And the OP doesn't have anything they can use to define row order.

Comment: @SeanLange: Of course, I forgot the `ORDER BY`. And if you're correct and there's no column to sort the OP is doomed :-)

Comment: Hello. My bad for not including the column in which you could ORDER BY. Anyway, this helped me solve my problem. Thank you so much.